# Why did my code timed out if required time complexity is met?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I tried to solve CodeWars kata and got stuck on the time out error. I read in the comments  that the code should be O(n) complexity. Though, my code is actually O(n). So, maybe i had made some mistakes and so on. Why did not this work? Should anyone explain why my code is slower than O(n) pls?

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool scramble(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
    string copy = s1;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < s2.size(); ++i)
    {
        size_t found = copy.find(string(1,s2[i]));
        if (found != string::npos)
        {
            sum++;
            copy.erase(found,1);
        }
    }
    if (sum == s2.size()){return true;}
    return false;

}
```

Comment: `erase` and `find` generally have a linear time complexity. So your complexity is in O(s1.length()*s2.length())

Comment: *Though, my code is actually O(n).* -- It isn't `O(n)`.  What if the `string` is 1000 characters, and you call `erase` on the first character?  All of those characters ahead of the erased character must be moved up one place.  Maybe if you used a different data structure, such as a `std::list<char>`, maybe you could make the claim of `O(n)`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks for the advice. I'll figure it out.

Comment: Even with std::list, you'll be executing a `copy.find` which has O(n) time complexity, resulting in O(n^2) for the whole program again.

Comment: @kirillshvedov -- What is "CodeWars kata"?  What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Complete the function scramble(str1, str2) that returns true if a portion of str1 characters can be rearranged to match str2, otherwise returns false.

Notes:

    Only lower case letters will be used (a-z). No punctuation or digits will be included.
    Performance needs to be considered

Input strings s1 and s2 are null terminated.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie https://www.codewars.com/kata/55c04b4cc56a697bb0000048/train/cpp

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the kata's name is "Scramblies"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest issue I see is that `copy.find()` & `copy.erase()` are more expensive than you think. They are essentially O(n), and since it's in a O(n) for loop, you have at least O(n^2) run time.

By counting letters, you can avoid that altogether. The code below is O(3n) --> O(n). It also passed all tests.

```cpp
#include<string>
#include <array>

bool scramble(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2){
  std::array<int, 26> s1LetterCounts{0};
  for (auto& i : s1) {
    ++s1LetterCounts[i - 'a'];
  }
  
  for (auto& i : s2) {
    --s1LetterCounts[i - 'a'];
  }
  
  for (auto& i : s1LetterCounts) {
    if (i < 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  return true;
}
```

The final if condition is to satisfy the substring requirement. `s1` may contain characters that `s2` doesn't, so the loop where `s2` decrements from the counting array may leave some positive counts, but it should never leave a negative.

I could likely do a little more with regards to performance (merge 2nd and 3rd loops), but it passed as-is.